# Django - can't update existing data in database, doesn't update

Tags: django

I have an authenticated user with related data, such as a file which the user uploaded and a description and ID number associated with the user. (The user previously used a Document model and associated form to upload the original info. This is working fine. Now I have an EditForm which I want to use to update the user ID and description, but when I call save, it doesn't get updated. Here is the views and models. I can print to the console my new data as entered in the form, I'm just not saving it correctly. Thanks in advance.

views.py:

```
def edit(request):
items = Document.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)
for object in items:
    print(object.id_number,'original') # shows original data
    print(object.description,'original')  # shows original data       
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditForm(request.POST, instance = request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        post  = form.save(commit = False)
        post.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        post.id_number = form.cleaned_data['id_number']
        
        print(post.id_number,'############') #shows form data as entered
        print(post.description,'!!!!!!!!!!!')   #shows form data as entered         
        post.save()
    else:
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'form': form})
    messages.info(request, 'Successfully Saved')
    return redirect('home')
else:
    form = EditForm( instance = request.user)
return render(request, 'edit.html',{
    'form':form, 'items':items
    })
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


# Create your models here.
class Document(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by =  models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        #return self.document
        # return 'ID'
        return f" {self.description} {self.created_by}  {self.uploaded_at} "

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Uploaded Documents"    



class EditInfo(models.Model):
    owner =  models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True , null=True)    
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True) 
    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.description} {self.id_number} " 



 class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EditInfo
        fields = ('description', 'id_number')
```

Comment: Please also include **EditForm** class in your question

Comment: class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EditInfo
        fields = ('description', 'id_number')

Comment: sorry, how do I add this an formatted code

Comment: edit your question and add it formatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **EditForm** is related to **EditInfo** model so it's will only updates *description* and *id_number* on **EditInfo**.

So what you need to do is to access to **Document** model like so:

```
if form.is_valid():
    for object in items:
        object.id_number = form.cleaned_data['id_number']
        object.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        object.save()
    form.save()
```

And you can use **Atmoic Transaction** if you want to make sure all data will changes together

```
if form.is_valid():
    with transaction.atomic():
        for object in items:
            object.id_number = form.cleaned_data['id_number']
            object.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            object.save()
        form.save()
```

don't forget to import transaction on top of your code:

```
from django.db import transaction
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank-you that works. For atomic , do i just add the decorator?

Comment: Cool, check the answer again I have added how to use it.

Comment: Do I need form.save ? (as well as object.save to send to the database)

Comment: wouldn't that update every object in your Model?  with the same values?

Comment: yes, object.save() will update the data in Document model.. but form.save() will save the data in EditInfo model

Comment: Thanks both the replies  @taha maathof - yes maybe I just want the main data base